# Bugzilla Search Bug Reports by date range eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, bugzilla

I want to search for all the bug reports in the [Eclipse bug repository](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) that have been filed and fixed between January 2008 and November 2010. How do I search for bugs from a date range in Bugzilla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Advanced Search form, which is a "tab" in the general Search page, instead of the default Simple Search.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/query.cgi

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/query.cgi?format=advanced